# Conceptually speaking, how would I pull facebook wall posts from 100k users?

Tags: design, api, facebook

Not looking for any code snippets here, so here goes:

Let's say 100,000 users on my web app have authorized my application to connect to facebook (with or without `offline_access`). I want to build a sort of "pull" mechanism, whereby when a user posts to their facebook wall, I can grab it from the Graph API and store it locally on my server.

I would assume that this would require a call to the Graph API every *n* minutes to pull their latest wall posts.

Ideally, this would be done for Twitter as well. I know LinkedIn does this, but I am not sure of the exact details.

Question 1: I'd need to make an individual Graph API call for each user, right?

Question 2: If I suddenly bombard the Graph API with 100k Graph API calls, wouldn't I run head-first into the rate limiter?

Question 2b: If not, what if I had a million users? Surely...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not really any need to build the "pull" mechanism when you can have [Facebook `POST` you graph updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/). I'm not entirely sure about limits on this service.

As for your individual questions:

> Question 1: I'd need to make an individual Graph API call for each
>   user, right?

No. You can issue requests for multiple users. See the "Selection" section [in this doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). However, I'm sure that there's a limit to the number of users that you can query at once (not sure about the number though).

> Question 2: If I suddenly bombard the Graph API with 100k Graph API
>   calls, wouldn't I run head-first into the rate limiter?

Yep, which is probably why you'd want to have the data pushed to you rather than pulled.

> Question 2b: If not, what if I had a million users? Surely...

Don't build for what you *think*, or *hope* you might have.. Build for what you *know* you have. Refactor and optimize when the time comes. Not now.

Comment: I had no idea you could subscribe to real-time updates from Facebook... is this a new feature? It seems to be exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: I don't remember seeing it the last time I developed something using the graph API, so it's probably relatively new.

Comment: Seems like your answer to Question 2 would imply that its better to design for today and not worry about the application being able to scale. I am not saying this is wrong I am just asking if this is what you meant and was hoping you could add some detail to why you think that's the best approach. It's seems counter productive. I may be over simplifying your answer.

Comment: Do you mean 2b? Of course horizontal scaling architecture is best practice, but not *always* a strict requirement. Sometimes (especially in a prototype stage), it's best to just getting something up and running and then refactor as required rather than build an overly complex solution based on what you *think* you'll have as a user load. If your app bombs, then you didn't spend all that extra time building the perfectly scaling application.

Comment: Having said that, ensuring that you haven't design scalability out should definitely be a core requirement of any architecture. This should be handled nicely by abstract, modular subsystems.

Comment: My main motivation for asking is because there is a trade-off between coding to scale, and the time required to do so. e.g. I don't mind putting in an extra 10 minutes to possibly save an hour of refactoring. Obviously, there's a point of diminishing return, but where that point lies varies between developers :)

Comment: @Julian: Couldn't agree more :)